# Plot the values of different days of a variable in one same plot from 0-24h

Tags: r, plot, xts

I need to overlay multiple days of a variable onto one plot. The values are recorded in a non-uniform way. Say there can be two values with a second of difference and others with a minute from the prior value. 
I have a dataset called `eventos` which has a column named `fecha` as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` and a column named `velocidad`, both as a factor and I need to compare the values recorded according to the time of the day.

I have created and xts variable xts.velocidad using the dates as POSIXct which, just for visualization purposes, I can separate in days to plot alone as xts.velocidad["20180924"].

The post that follows by Bruno Caram Muller and answered by Jimbou almost answer my question but not close enough to what I am looking for:
[How to plot data in R from different days overlayed in only one day (based on hours:minutes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490435/how-to-plot-data-in-r-from-different-days-overlayed-in-only-one-day-based-on-ho)

```
head(eventos$fecha)
[1] 2018-09-27 13:32:45 2018-09-27 13:32:46 2018-09-27 13:32:48
[4] 2018-09-27 13:32:49 2018-09-27 13:32:54 2018-09-27 13:32:55
1407340 Levels: 2018-09-27 13:32:45 2018-09-27 13:32:46 ... 2019-02-26 13:33:34

head(eventos$velocidad)
[1] 2222 2222 2340 2340 2570 2570
```

I wish to have a code to simply plot one day on top of another where I can differentiate each day`s record.

Comment: It would help considerably to have an unambiguous small reproducible sample of data. This is often done best with `dput(head(x))`, since pasting just the console representation of the data can mask several things.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [reproducible example in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Moreover, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers.